# I need to find an error from this python randint card game

Tags: python, prng

```
def simple_game():
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,10):
        if pick() % 13 != 0 :
            total = total + pick() % 13
        else:
            total = total // 2
    return total
```

after generating a random number (function not shown above), player's score will be reduced by half if the number is one of 13, 26, 39. Or else, it will be increased by the number%13.

What is wrong with this function?

Comment: Don't you have to do something like `mypick = pick() %13` and then `if mypick !=0` and `total += mypick` ?

Comment: @sshashank124 it's the random card generator function. You get a random card in range of 0-52

Answer (score 3):

it's probably in `pick`. if that's where you get your random number, you call it twice, thus getting two (probably) different results.

Answer (score 1):

You more than likely need to set a variable for the return value of pick().  As if stands now its getting called every time within the for loop.